# Not able to run my selenium script in parallel from code deployed on remote server

Tags: selenium

From local machine  i am able to run my selenium script in parallel on local selenium grid but scripts are not running when running from code deployed on remote server.

I was trying to run multiple selenium scripts in parallel on local selenium grid. The scripts work fine when I trigger the scripts from my local machine but when I deploy the same code on a remote server and trigger the scripts the scripts are failing.

Comment: You should insert an error message / stacktrace then, so we can help better.

Comment: And probably you should show the code. You have to make the problem reproducible, otherwise it's usually hard to help

Comment: Expalin properly
at least the Error

Comment: When I deploy the code on a remote server and try to run the scripts in parallel the scripts are working in some browsers and get stuck in others. I am using RemoteWebDriver.

Comment: DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

   cap.setCapability("browser", "Firefox");
   cap.setCapability("browser_version", "42.0");
   cap.setCapability("os", "Windows");
   cap.setCapability("os_version", "7");
   cap.setCapability("resolution", "1024x768");
   cap.setCapability("browserstack.debug", "true");
   cap.setCapability("browserstack.local", "true");
   //          cap.setBrowserName("firefox");
   //          cap.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
   driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://173.36.54.119:4444/wd/hub"), cap);
  }

Answer (score 0):

You Should use `RemoteWebDriver` and not `WebDriver` the difference is WebDriver works on local machine but when you execute your application from a distant machine you need to use RemoteWebDriver